# How do I call a key from my dictionary and print its corresponding values?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble getting user_input to search for keys inside my dictionary, it doesn't return anything at the moment. I have print('bleg') as a placeholder as I test it, but my goal is to have user_input call its corresponding values from the dictionary.

```
my_file = open('grades.csv','r')
gradescsv = my_file.readlines()
skipheader = 3

records = {}
for i in gradescsv:
    cols = i.split(',')
    if(skipheader == 0):
        students = {}
        courses = {}
        course1 ={}
        course2 = {}
        
        course1['hw1'] = cols[2]
        course1['hw2'] = cols[3]
        course1['midterm'] = cols[4]
        course1['final'] = cols[5]
        
        course2['hw1'] = cols[6]
        course2['hw2'] = cols[7]
        course2['midterm'] = cols[8]
        course2['final'] = cols[9]
        
        courses['Course 1'] = course1
        courses['Course 2'] = course2

        records[cols[0]+''+cols[1]] = courses
    else:
      skipheader -= 1

user_input = input('Enter student name: ')
if user_input in records:
  print('bleg')
```

Comment: Could you post CSV or at least a few rows? If the statement is executed only once otherwise you are only decreasing skipheader,  doesn't seem correct.

Comment: The `input()` function reads a line from the input, converts the line into a **string** by removing the trailing newline, and returns it. Therefore there is probably a type mismatch that causes `if user_input in records` to be `False`. A good place to start debugging would be to print `records` and see how the keys are stored in it.
In addition, it is preferred to use a context manager to open files (i.e `with open`).